# C++ Matrix multiplication program with MPI using serial algorithm and another one using parallel version

Tags: c++, mpi, matrix-multiplication, ms-mpi

The program have two methods to calculate the matrix product:

one using serial algorithm

```
//Function to multiply matrices using serial algorithm
int** multiplySerial(int** matrixA, int** matrixB, int rowsA, int colsA, int colsB) {
    int** result = new int*[rowsA];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsA; i++) {
        result[i] = new int[colsB];
        for (int j = 0; j < colsB; j++) {
            result[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < colsA; k++) {
                result[i][j] += matrixA[i][k] * matrixB[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

another one using parallel version.

```
//Function to multiply matrices using parallel algorithm
int** multiplyParallel(int** matrixA, int** matrixB, int rowsA, int colsA, int colsB, int rank, int size) {
    int** result = new int*[rowsA];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsA; i++) {
        result[i] = new int[colsB];
        for (int j = 0; j < colsB; j++) {
            result[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    int* sendbuf = new int[colsA];
    int* recvbuf = new int[colsA];
    MPI_Status status;

    for (int k = 0; k < colsA; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rowsA; i++) {
            sendbuf[i] = matrixA[i][k];
        }

        MPI_Allgather(sendbuf, rowsA, MPI_INT, recvbuf, rowsA, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        for (int j = rank; j < colsB; j += size) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rowsA; i++) {
                result[i][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < colsA; k++) {
                    result[i][j] += recvbuf[k] * matrixB[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    delete[] sendbuf;
    delete[] recvbuf;

    return result;
}
```

Both take two same matrices and return the resulting matrix product.
The methods are tested with some large randomly generated matrices
here is the random matrix generator function

```
// Function to generate random matrices
void generateRandomMatrix(int** matrix, int rows, int columns) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
}
```

and compare the results for serial and parallel versions.
and lastly I Calculated the speedup and efficiency of parallel version.

here is the memory deallocation for memory management

```
// Function to deallocate memory for a matrix
void deallocateMatrix(int** matrix, int rows) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        delete[] matrix[i];
    }
    delete[] matrix;
}
```

here is the Main method

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

   int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int rowsA = 10; // Number of rows in matrix A
    int colsA = 10; // Number of columns in matrix A
    int colsB = 10; // Number of columns in matrix B

    // Generate random matrices A and B
    int** matrixA = nullptr;
    int** matrixB = nullptr;

    if (rank == 0) {
        matrixA = new int*[rowsA];
        matrixB = new int*[colsA];

        for (int i = 0; i < rowsA; i++) {
            matrixA[i] = new int[colsA];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < colsA; i++) {
            matrixB[i] = new int[colsB];
        }

        generateRandomMatrix(matrixA, rowsA, colsA);
        generateRandomMatrix(matrixB, colsA, colsB);
    }

    // Broadcast matrix B to all processes
    MPI_Bcast(&matrixB[0][0], colsA * colsB, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // Calculate the product using serial algorithm
    double startTime = MPI_Wtime();
    int** serialResult = multiplySerial(matrixA, matrixB, rowsA, colsA, colsB);
    double endTime = MPI_Wtime();
    double serialTime = endTime - startTime;

    // Calculate the product using parallel algorithm
    startTime = MPI_Wtime();
    int** parallelResult = multiplyParallel(matrixA, matrixB, rowsA, colsA, colsB, rank, size);
    endTime = MPI_Wtime();
    double parallelTime = endTime - startTime;

    // Compare the results of serial and parallel algorithms
    bool isEqual = true;
    if (rank == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rowsA; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colsB; j++) {
                if (serialResult[i][j] != parallelResult[i][j]) {
                    isEqual = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isEqual) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Print results
    if (rank == 0) {
        if (isEqual) {
            cout << "Results are equal." << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Results are not equal." << endl;
        }

        double speedup = serialTime / parallelTime;
        double efficiency = speedup / size;

        cout << "Serial Time: " << serialTime << " seconds" << endl;
        cout << "Parallel Time: " << parallelTime << " seconds" << endl;
        cout << "Speedup: " << speedup << endl;
        cout << "Efficiency: " << efficiency << endl;

        deallocateMatrix(matrixA, rowsA);
        deallocateMatrix(matrixB, colsA);
    }

    deallocateMatrix(serialResult, rowsA);
    deallocateMatrix(parallelResult, rowsA);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

these are the problems with the code
first the result matrices are not the same
[result not equal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yyur.png)
[here is an  example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzPZJ.png)
second when i run the code with multiple processors it crashes
[when i run it with this command mpiexec -n 2 ./matrix_multiplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcXao.png)

Comment: you are overwritting `sendbuf` when you populate it, and you gather way too much data in recvbuf. First trim your code down to a [mcve], and populate your input data with simple values so you can easily validate the result.

Comment: So many `*`'s, manual memory management, `using namespace std;`, this could do with a "modern C++" makeover.

Comment: How do the results differ? Could you send a sample?

Comment: You can click to the link in the description to see example picture.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet now I have divided the methods could you please check it.

Comment: since `MPI_Allgather()` gathers `rowsA` elements from each rank, the minimum size for `recvbuf` is `rowsA * size` and I do not think this is true.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Could you please give me a detailed review in the whole part. sorry I'm new for c++.

Comment: Convince me you have made an honest effort, and clearly describe where you are stuck at first. And then I will likely help you

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I tried to debug where the problem is the program crashes in the multiplyParallel method when I tried to gather values of `sendbuf` from each process and store them in the `recvbuf` by using `MPI_Allgather`.  but I think I don't understand the MPI_Allgather and it's because I'm not familiar with MPI.

Comment: Can you describe in plain English what you want to achieve with MPI_Allgather() ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet After scattering matrix A across all processes using `MPI_Scatter()`. Each process  has  a column of `matrix A()` (`sendbuf`) . to work with the matrix multiplication each process needs to have access to the entire column of `matrix A` so `MPI_Allgather()` gather the values of `sendbuf`from all processes and store in `recvbuf`.
In simple word I used `MPI_Allgather` to ensures that each process has the complete column of matrix A by gathering the scattered portions from all processes.

Comment: I did not see any `MPI_Scatter()` in your code.